# Why is my cat scared of a box?

Tags: cats, behavior

I put out a box of blankets thinking that my cat would like it, but as soon as my cat saw the box she ran under my bed. She usually loves boxes or bags with clothes that I need to return, but she hates the box that I have in my room. She does come out to eat, but she eyes the box as if it were an enemy.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn’t worry too much about it. Sometimes cats have indecipherable opinions about things.

It could be any number of things that makes the cat wary of the box:

1. the scent of something that was originally in the box (or maybe the blankets) could be offensive to the cat.
2. The box made a sound when you set it up that the cat didn’t like.
3. The box is a larger size than the cat is used to.

I’m not sure by the question if this box was specifically set up for the cat, or if you’re using it to store the blankets in. If it’s for the cat and she doesn’t like it, try setting up a different box or putting it in a different area. You could also try to feed the cat treats around to box to encourage positive feedback. If the box really bothers her and it’s not specifically for her, either move it where she doesn’t go, or just let her get used to it.